# Ошибка при генерации signature FreeKassa Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

хочу использовать API FreeKassa на Node.js и у меня происходит ошибка при генерации signature (ниже ошибка и код генерации)

Скрин ошибки

[image: скрин ошибки]

Код генерации signature

```
    const apiKey = process.env.FREEKASSA_API_KEY || ''

    body.signature = crypto
        .createHmac('sha256', apiKey)
        .update(Object.keys(body).sort().join('|'))
        .digest('hex')
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://docs.freekassa.ru/#section/2.-Vvedenie/2.2.-Podpis-zaprosov

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добрый день, хочу использовать API FreeKassa на Node.js и у меня происходит ошибка при генерации signature (ниже ошибка и код генерации)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1514385/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-api-freekassa-%d0%bd%d0%b0-node-js-%d0%b8-%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1)

Comment: Задавать вопросы дважды нельзя по правилам площадки.